# Django: Which database call is faster/better?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm building an online internet game that people can log in to play. When people play a Game, they create a Result. In addition, they can Like Games and Results.

My main question is, is there a significant difference in the way that I make calls to the database? There is a table for Games and there is a table for User Profiles. Would it make a difference if I save likes to a Game on the Game table, or if I save likes to a game_likes field on the User Profile table?

For example, if my UserProfile looked like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profile')
    games_liked = models.ManyToManyField(Game, related_name='games_liked')
```

and my Game model looked like this:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
```

Which would be better for making calls to the database? This:

```
games_liked = Game.objects.filter(likes=request.user).order_by('-pubdate')
```

versus:

```
games_liked = request.user.user_profile.games_liked.all()
```

I feel like the second example is better because it uses direct relations to pick the games instead of querying the entire Game index to figure out which games have been liked by the user, but a friend I was talking to said that Django and SQL index the databases so that it would be the same either way. Does it actually matter?

Edit: My current site is saving to both a likes field on the Game and a game_likes field on the UserProfile, then counting the Game's likes field for likes and seeking the UserProfile game_likes field to see if the user has liked a game or not, but I don't know if it actually makes a difference or if duplicating the tables makes it not worth the difference in seek time.

Comment: Have you tried implementing both options then measuring performance in your environment?

Comment: The first step in understanding this would be looking at the SQL generated by Django for these queries (look on StackOverflow if you don't know how to do that). My suspicion is that the query is the same in both cases (leaving aside the `order_by`). I'm not sure what you mean by "direct relations to pick the games instead of querying the entire Game index", but note that `games_liked` is not part of the `UserProfile` table - using `ManyToManyField` causes a whole new table to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.user.user_profile` makes an SQL query to get user profile, then `user_profile.games_liked.all()` makes second sql query to get liked games.

So, form this point of view `Game.objects.filter(likes=request.user)` is better.

You can check what sql was executed, in shell, by looking into `connection.queries` variable (available only if setting DEBUG=True)

```
from django.db import connection

user.user_profile.games_liked.all()
Game.objects.filter(likes=user)._as_sql(connection)

print(connection.queries)
```

Anyway, your example seems broken. ManyToMany field creates whole new table  to store relationships. And you have linked games twice:

- UserProfile -> _m2m_table -> Games (by UserProfile.games_liked)
- User -> _m2m_table -> Games (by Games.likes)

You should remove one field.

Django creates shortcuts to get access to relation from opposite side. That is what `related_name` stands for. So for your Game model, use have access to users by `game.likes`, and from user you have access to games by `user.likes`, b/c you have declared `related_name='likes'`

Comment: Thanks for this, that makes sense. I wasn't aware that the ManyToManyField was creating another set of tables that Django would have to scan, which would cut out any of the calls I'd save by putting that information in the User Profile.